# How do i create transparent triangle with thin gray borders css

Tags: css, css-shapes

I want to create a triangle that is white but has got thin gray borders.
I have tried this code

```css
.arrow-down {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 20px solid #f00;
  border-right: 20px solid transparent;
  border-left: 20px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow-down"></div>
```

But it gave me triangle filled with red.

Comment: I am surprised that it gave you a triangle. Are you cure you got a triangle?

Comment: It's from this article: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/

Comment: @EdHeal Yes i did.You can try it yoursel

Comment: I don't know what your requirements are, but you can use linear-gradient, take a look at this https://jsfiddle.net/Konrud/7z4zyLy9/

Comment: @dippas the op is not too clear  actually : transparent in the title, white in the topic ... which is what to care about :) ? red in the code for gray, ....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

did you mean something like this?
You can change the color of the border with: `border-top-color: #B1B1B1;` 
Once you would like change the dimensions of the triangle, you have to change it everywhere.

```css
.arrow-down {
  position: relative;
}
.arrow-down:after,
.arrow-down:before {
  border-top: 20px solid white;
  border-left: 20px solid transparent;
  border-right: 20px solid transparent;
  margin-left: -20px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -20px;
  content: '';
  left: 50%;
}
.arrow-down:before {
  border-right: 20px solid transparent;
  border-top: 20px solid;
  border-left: 20px solid transparent;
  border-top-color: #B1B1B1;
  bottom: -22px;
  margin-left: -20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow-down"></div>
```

Answer (score 6):

You can just rotate the arrow div and adjust the border colors to suit.

The inner part of the arrow can be any color you want...here it's transparent because no background color has been applied.

```css
.arrow-down {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-width:1px;
  border-style:solid;
  border-color:transparent grey grey transparent;
  transform:rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow-down"></div>
```

Comment: I have the exact requirement but need to add arrow up at the top of my box- rotating 180 deg changes orientation but what do I do to place this arrow on top of my box?

Answer (score 0):

```
.arrow-down {
  border: solid black;
  border-width: 0 .12em .12em 0;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: .20em;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

Comment: please add some words or a fiddle to your code next time.